# How do i access file parameter in our java code which is send by jenkins job

Tags: java, jenkins

1)How can we access Jenkins file parameter in our java code
2)What we have to send in Goal to initialise file parameter
3)Is it possible we should not select file via file tab at the time of build with parameter? 
if yes then how?

I have tried to upload a file via IN jenkins configuration - 
Gemeral -> file is parameterized -> file parameter -> send location

after saving click on build with parameter and upload the file then build

I am able to build by this but not able to access it in Java code

Comment: What are you building with? Maven? Ant? Gradle?

Comment: When you say "Jenkins file parameter" do you mean a parameter specified in a Jenkinsfile?

Comment: I am building with maven

Comment: Jenkins file parameter mean parameter specified in a file (upload a file via Jenkins)